# resignFirstResponder programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I remove a keyboard from the view as a result of the return key being touched when the UITextField was created programmatically.

If the UITextField was called in the viewDidLoad I know how to do this, but the UITextField was created as a result of an -(IBAction).

I created my UITextField programmatically.  I know the resignFirstResponder removes the keyboard.  I have it set up to do so when the screen is taped outsie the keyboard.  I also have it working to where if the user triggers the IBAction with the UIButton related to the UITextField the keyboard goes away.  I also want to be able to hide the keyboard when the user selects return from the keyboard.

Comment: What is with all the down votes on these answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

You'll need to set your text field's `delegate` to `self` first, though:

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
```

Or, you could right-click-drag from the text field in IB to little orange circle at the bottom.

[image: IB]

Comment: Why do you say "return NO;"?  It works either way.  Just would like to know whay you would put NO for the BOOL.

Comment: @James Because you *have* to return something, and NO is what came out when I rolled some dice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make yourself a UITextFieldDelegate and implement:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

Make sure you set the textField's delegate to `self` when you create it.